# Not be able to assign string with special symbol in to the label

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsstring, symbols

I am trying to assign string value containing special symbol 'β' into Label. But 'β' is converted into 'Œ≤' in the label.

I have tried like this -

```
NSString *temp = [[array2 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Class"];
NSString *classes = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Œ≤" withString:@"β"];

lblClass.text = classes;
NSString *temp = [lblClass.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Œ≤" withString:@"β"];

NSLog(@"class is %@",classes);        
NSLog(@"class - %@", lblClass.text);
NSLog(@"class - %@", temp);
```

The values in console are -

```
2012-07-27 14:50:51.249 MedicationProfilesApp[2539:207] class is Sympathomimetic / β - 2 Agonist / Brochodilator
2012-07-27 14:51:02.198 MedicationProfilesApp[2539:207] class - Sympathomimetic / Œ≤ - 2 Agonist / Brochodilator
2012-07-27 14:51:03.375 MedicationProfilesApp[2539:207] class - Sympathomimetic / β - 2 Agonist / Brochodilator
```

What can be the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code it may help you

```
 NSString *str = [@"Your special symbol" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But can you please explain where should i put the character that i want to replace ? Means with which sting should i use your code?

Comment: in my above code at @"Your special symbol" use your special symbol in place of @"Your special symbol".

then 
    yourLabel.text = str;

Comment: sorry i still cant understand it. Can you please explain with my example ?

Comment: NSString *str = [@"β" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

lblClass.text = str;

Now this label will have β symbol.

Comment: ok. but that special symbol is contained in string (comes from array). And i want to assign that string to label , not just that symbol

Comment: NSArray *aAry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"β",@"Ó",nil];
    NSString *aStrSymbol = [aAry objectAtIndexPath:0];
    NSString *str = [[NSString stringWithFormat:aStrSymbol] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    lblClass.text = str;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest search the ASCII code for that and use that instead.